My math professor is Chinese. Is it okay for me to speak Chinese to her in office hours?
My math professor is Chinese. She and I both speak Mandarin Chinese (普通话) fluently. The syllabus says that it is good etiquette for everyone to speak & write in English during class, and for all school emails.
Is it okay for me to speak to her Chinese to her in office hours?

This reminds me of my grad school life in the US. My PhD advisor is a Chinese, so am I. In my very first semester in the US, my English was horrible, and so we spoke Chinese occasionally. But she encouraged me to speak English and not be to afraid of making mistakes. So only in the circumstance I really couldn't speak English properly, I spoke Chinese to her.

Ask, but expect a no. My native language is not English, and since moving to the USA speaking that language is reserved for speaking it with my family in the old country.
The context switching is very heavy, and especially and I am pretty strict about avoiding it.

Note that if you get into a habit of speaking with her in Mandarin when one-to-one, this may quickly slip into you also using Mandarin with her when there are other people around. Not only can it quickly become rude, it may also give the impression to others that there could be some sort of preference/bias in your favour due to this.

I suppose the reason for the syllabus rules is intelligibility by third parties (for example, it would be impolite to speak Mandarin (or German) in a classroom full of English speakers, cutting them out; and emails may be forwarded/reviewed etc.). These reasons do not apply to a tête-à-tête oral conversation, so it's up to whether you both agree.

I would ask your professor directly during office hours rather than relying on us.
There may be some good reasons to talk in English besides etiquette. For example, it's good practice in English especially if your education is going to be in English. Even if your English is already quite good, if you'd propose speaking in Mandarin that suggests to me you're less comfortable in English so could benefit from the comfort of practice.

Yes, it should be fine, unless she indicates otherwise. One of the purposes of the rule in the syllabus is, perhaps, for students to gain practice in English. But another is that in public situations (three or more people), a common language is best, and that might be English.
But private conversations are probably different. Ask her if you are unsure.
Another issue, since this is mathematics, with a specialized vocabulary, it is important to learn that vocabulary if you intend to continue in math. That might imply English is the language of choice, or not. I don't know to what extent the vocabulary of math is international.

Math vocabulary IME tends to be more diverged on more basic concepts, and more converged on more advanced topics.

@ave I think that's generally true, but to be clear the terminology at university-level math classes is still quite different in different languages (and not just terms, but also how statements are phrased).

At research level maths a significant proportion of specialized vocabulary essentially only exists in English. If you listen to a research talk in German (which is fairly close to English and also has a rich maths vocabulary) some words will still be in English simply because there is not translation of the maths term to any other language. Example, a line bundle in algebraic geometric may be 'ample', to my knowledge, the math term only exists in English.

This is alluded to in @Buffy's answer, but the answer depends on how well office hours are attended. If you are meeting the professor one-on-one in office hours, speaking Mandarin Chinese does not inconvenience other students.
But in many courses, office hours are well-attended: students come not only to ask their own unique questions, but to hear the answers to other students' questions. In such scenarios, office hours are more like a discussion section, with the topics driven by the problems that students are having with the material. A student might never be able to ask his own question, but that's okay because other students have the same question.
And in such scenarios, it will be highly annoying to other students if you are not using English as a common language. The whole office hour may pass without them ever getting help in their own language.

I would change it from "getting help in their own language" to "getting help in a language they understand"

This is mostly anecdotal, but in my experience, scientific communication happens based on the participants. If everyone speaks the same language, it's that language; if a single one in the group does not speak that language, it's English. I did my masters under a supervisor from my own country in Sweden, while my other two teammates were German and my supervisor was fluent in all three languages. We just kept switching back and forth between them. It's not like it's a big deal - just use whatever is the most convenient. We found ourself, for example, switch to English even if it was just the two of us, simply because it was easier to express science on that language.
Ultimately, it's whatever you two find suitable. Just ask your prof if he'd prefer English or Chinese, and prepare that the answer will be "whatever you prefer.

When non-Chinese speakers are present: Use English.
For one-on-one office hours:

Begin with English, then follow the professor's lead.
If she switches to Chinese, you may do so as well.
If she reverts to English mid-conversation, you should follow suit.

When you're the only one in her office, but the door is open: This is a gray area.
Assuming the professor is a Chinese immigrant, I'm providing a U.S. perspective supported by some data.
Other answers seem to treat Chinese as if it were any other language. From a U.S. perspective, I believe this is an oversimplification. Chinese may be unique in this respect: Chinese people are significantly overrepresented in many fields of mathematics. However, discrimination against them, if not ongoing, is still a recent memory.
I posit that if she has survived in academia long enough to become a professor, she is likely aware of the complexities surrounding language choice. My point is that a Chinese professor may need to consider factors that are less relevant to, say, a Swedish professor. Hence the suggestion: Always follow her lead.

Moreover, if you're talking in Chinese, someone who doesn't know Chinese has no way of knowing if your professor is leaking secrets to an agent of the Chinese government. Yes, this has happened.

Another difference between Chinese and other non-English (but European) languages is, that for example if the door is open and someone overhears you, if you spoke for example German, even if others don't understand it, native English speakers can at least understand the broad topic, the tonality, and the mood of the conversation. Chinese is different enough that they would not even know whether it's a serious conversation, a friendly chat, or a scolding.
